# Category subcategory recursion

Tags: fuelphp

I hope if someone can help me with example for fuelphp unlimited nesting by using ORM or CRUD to create categories and sub categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my [nested sets package](https://github.com/fuel-packages/fuel-nestedsets) to create nested set tree structures in a table.